# I'm trying to use the Copy Rotation constraint but the "Mix" property doesn't exist

Tags: constraints

I'm trying to follow a YouTube tutorial on rigging and animating a book. In the video, he uses the Copy Rotation constraint and changes the "Mix" property to "Add". My version of Blender doesn't seem to have this mix property, and the book doesn't behave as it should without it. What should I do?

Comment: What version of blender are you using? Mine has it, using 3.6.

Comment: 2.8 it seems like. I'll try to update and redo it :)

Comment: 2.83 has it too. Can you add a link to the tutorial please? If you pause the video at the time where that constraint is used, right-click on it, and select "Copy video URL at current time" that will add a timestamp to the link so that we don't have to watch the whole tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnEason Here is the tutorial, though it should be fixed if I just update blender. https://youtu.be/geyC6FfMFf8?t=271

Comment: That tutorial was done in Blender 2.9.3 but that setting is certainly available right from 2.83 to the current 3.6 version of Blender.